# Can't open specific layers with Qgis nor OGR

Tags: qgis, python, ogr

I'm working with mutliple sets of layers in order to create a new one.
As I need to load them directly from the internet, I use both /vsizip/ and /vsicurl/

But I'm stuck at loading one of them.
Here is what I do:

```
from osgeo import ogr
address_shp = ogr.Open("/vsizip//vsicurl/http://bano.openstreetmap.fr/BAN_odbl/BAN_odbl_01-shp.zip")
if address_shp is None:
    print ('Address : download successfull')
else:
    print ('Address : download failed')

parcels_shp = ogr.Open("/vsizip//vsicurl/https://cadastre.data.gouv.fr/data/etalab-cadastre/latest/shp/departements/01/cadastre-01-batiments-shp.zip")
if parcels_shp is None:
    print ('Parcels : download successfull')
else:
    print ('Parcels : download failed')
```

Output:

```
>Address : download successfull
>Parcels : download failed
```

I got the same result directly in QGis.
So, does /vsicurl/ handle https protocol? Or is the problem elsewhere?

OS : Windows 7 / Qgis 2.8.26 & 3.4.2

Comment: It works for me by omitting the slash after cadastre-01-batiments-shp.zip.

Comment: @AndreJ My bad, it isn't present in my code, I removed it from the question. What are your ogr version and os?

Comment: I can also `ogrinfo` the parcels connection string without any problems, with GDAL 2.3.1 on OSX

Comment: So it does work from command line ? It's really strange, I can't open it even with GDAL 2.3.2 using QGis 3.4

Comment: I'm using the same GDAL version on the Windows command line. And Linux Mint 18 with ubuntugis GDAL 2.2.2 and the same result. Since you are on Windows, take a look at http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-libcurl-and-the-certificates-and-Windows-td5322919.html

Comment: @AndreJ Same with `gdal.SetConfigOption('GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL', 'YES')` unfortunately

Comment: I used `set GDAL_HTTP_UNSAFESSL=YES` on the command line once. I'm not sure if SetConfigOption works the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @AndreJ for pointing [this](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-libcurl-and-the-certificates-and-Windows-td5322919.html) out.

The problems comes from the fact that curl (which is used by GDAL) may need a certificate for https protocol, depending on how it has been build (specifications [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html)).

Fortunately, one can be downloaded from a [secure source](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html), it must be named `curl-ca-bundle.crt` and dropped in one of the following directories in order to fix the problem (don't forget to close and reload QGis):

- QGis directory
- Current working directory
- Windows System directory (e.g. C:\windows\system32)
- Windows Directory (e.g. C:\windows)
- Directory specified in %PATH%